# parsing a string into tokens without strtok/lexer

Tags: c, string, parsing, gcc

I want to parse a string into an array of tokens . '\n' and ';' are delimiters , for e.g. :

```
hello;hello
world
```

should be converted to an array containing: `{"hello","hello","world"}`.

I tried many different methods for doing this and always I fail (since it needs a dynamic array of char * I have trouble with implementing it).

Please note that I cannot use strtok or lexical analyzer.

How may I do this ? Any points ?

EDIT : here is one of methods I tried to use but I get segmentation fault (maybe a memory access issue somewhere in my code) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct { 
    int fd;
    char *path;
    int size;
    char *mem;
    struct stat st;
} file;

file *readfile(char *path) {
    file *a=malloc(sizeof(file));
    a->path=path;
    a->fd=open(a->path,O_RDONLY);
    if(a->fd<0) return 0;
    fstat(a->fd,&a->st);
    a->size=a->st.st_size;
    a->mem=malloc(a->size);
    read(a->fd,a->mem,a->size);
    return a;
}

void releasefile(file *a) {
    free(a->mem);
    close(a->fd);
    free(a);
}

char **parse(int *w,file *a) {
    int i,j=0;
    w=0;
    for(i=0;i<=a->size;i++) {
        if(a->mem[i]=='\n' || a->mem[i]==';') { a->mem[i]='\0'; j++; }
    }
    char **out=malloc(sizeof(char *)*j);
    for(i=0;i<=a->size;i++) {
       if(a->mem[i-1]!='\0') continue;
       out[*w]=malloc(strlen(a->mem+i)+1);
       memcpy(out[*w],a->mem+i,strlen(a->mem+i)+1);
       w++;
           return out;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    file *a=readfile(argv[1]);
    int *w=malloc(sizeof(int));
    char **tokens=parse(w,a);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=*w;i++) {
        puts(tokens[i]);
        }
        releasefile(a);

    // ATM no need to check for mem leaks :)

}
```

Algorithm description : read file, put \0 where you see a delimiter, start and push tokens seprated by \0 into an array.

Comment: 1. Why "I cannot use x"? (i.e., you don't kow how, someone forbids you to, or what?) 2. What problem with `char *`? It would be useful if you post what you got -- even if it does not work.

Comment: Just do it manually, with loops, and `+`, and `==`, and things like that.

Comment: You could parse the string to determine the number of tokens and then `malloc` the array, or just start with an array of arbitrary size, and `realloc` as necessary.

Comment: The point is that you have to _work out_ how to do this, not just ask people.  It's the getting confused that helps you learn.

Comment: Please show one of the methods you tried.

Comment: I've added one of methods I used to question

Comment: @user145745: Your problem is that you are not adding the terminating NUL characters to the copied strings. Also, you don't put a NUL character at the end of the data you read from the file. In general, the amount of memory required by a NUL-terminated string is one byte more than its length, because the NUL is not counted in the length. NULs do not magically appear, either.

Comment: could you write the fixed code as an answer ?

Comment: Accomplished this type of thing with C++ with infinitely less hassle, and probably hardly any overhead. For this kind of thing, object orientation helps you wrap your head around things better. Especially when you get to the meat and potatoes.

Answer (score 3):

What has happened to computer science?

Anyway write a FSA - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Can do this using a table

Comment: ...using a table, a chair, a pencil and some paper, and perhaps a textbook.